# How to validate and post on Craigslist?

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I tried to validating my XML, but I did not get a proper response, anyone tell me how to validate my post operation? And what is the way of bulk posting with free of category and location?

I have free account in Craigslist. I use this code:

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL);    
ini_set('display_errors', '1');   
$name='my username';//$_POST['name']; // Get from form or get from DB one per xml
$password= 'my password';//$_POST['password'];
$id='my account ID';//$_POST['id'];    

$xmlStart='<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:cl="http://www.craigslist.org/about/cl-bulk-ns/1.0">';
$channelStart='<channel>';
$channelItems='<items>';
$channelItemsEnd='</items>';
$channelAuth='<cl:auth username="'.$name.'"
         password="'.$password.'"
         accountID="'.$id.'"/>';
$channelEnd='</channel>';
$xmlEnd='</rdf:RDF>';
$channelItems .='<rdf:li rdf:resource="$179000 / 3br - 3 Bed/1 Bath Great NE Heights         Locating!! No Bank Qualifying!! Owner Fi (NE Albuquerque)"/>'; 
$items='';       
//set the content type to xml
//header("Content-Type: text/xml");
// Initialize the xmlOutput variable
$xmlBody = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>';
$xmlBody = '<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/"
        xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:cl="http://www.craigslist.org/about/cl-bulk-ns/1.0">';
$xmlBody .= "<XML>";
// Run a select query to get my letest 6 items
// Connect to the MySQL database  
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db('new_listing');
//$dynamicList = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM listing ORDER BY id");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
// Create channel item string  
$channelItems .='';
         $id = $row['id'];
         $name = $row['username'];
         $password= $row['password'];
         $address = $row['address'];
         $Posting_type = $row['posting_type'];
         $category = $row['category'];
         $location = $row['location'];
         $posting_title = $row['posting_title'];
         $specific_loc = $row['specific_loc'];
         $postal = $row['postal_code'];
         $description = $row['description'];
         $reply_to = $row['reply_to'];
         $rent = $row['rent'];
         $sqft = $row['sqft'];
         $bedrooms = $row['bedrooms'];
         $bathrooms = $row['bathrooms'];
         $housing = $row['housing_type'];
         $laundry = $row['laundry'];
         $parking = $row['parking'];
         $wheelchair = $row['wheelchair'];
         $smoking = $row['smoking'];
         $furnished = $row['furnished'];
         $street = $row['street'];
         $cross_street = $row['cross_street'];
         $city = $row['city'];
         $zip_code = $row['zip_code'];
         $date_d = $row['date_d'];
         $time_t = $row['time_t'];
         $image = $row['images'];       
$items .= '
<item rdf:about="real estate">
<cl:category>"housing"</cl:category>
<cl:area>"NE Albuquerque"</cl:area>
<cl:housingInfo price="$179000"
                bedrooms="3"
                sqft="1400"/>
  <cl:replyEmail privacy="C">email address</cl:replyEmail>
  <cl:brokerInfo companyName="Your Company name"
               feeDisclosure="fee disclosure here" />
   <title>"$179000 / 3br - 3 Bed/1 Bath Great NE Heights Locating!! No Bank Qualifying!! Owner Fi (NE Albuquerque)"</title>
    <description><![CDATA["3 Bedroom, 1 Bath 1400sqft home with 1 car garage, 
    Lease With Option To Buy, No Bank Qualifying!! 
    Price $179,000, $1200 lease per month + $15,000 down 
    Great Location in NE Heights close to schools, shopping and jobs!! 
    Very Desirable Location! Call 505-264-7942 and ask for Robert"]]></description>
</item>';
// End while loop
}
mysql_close();
 // close the mysql database connection
//$xmlBody .= "</XML>";
   $xmlToSubmit=$xmlStart.$channelStart.$channelItems.$channelAuth.$channelItemsEnd.$channelEnd.$items.$xmlEnd;

class cURL {

var $headers;
var $user_agent;

function cURL()
{
    $this->headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';
    $this->headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';
    $this->user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Media Center PC 4.0)';
}



function post($url,$data) {
    $process = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->user_agent);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    $return = curl_exec($process);
    $info = curl_getinfo($process);
    curl_close($process);
    return $info;
}

}
 $cc = new cURL();
 $url = 'https://post.craigslist.org/bulk-rss/post';
 $output = $cc->post($url,$xmlToSubmit); 

 //echo $output;

  print_r($output); 
 } ?>
```

Comment: In general, when posting demo code, it is a good idea to remove private email addresses. I suspect R. Paulson would rather his/her email address did not appear here (about halfway down in the code).

Comment: As for the problem, does the XML generate? Is it valid? You can check these things prior to its being submitted. Then, see what cURL is doing. What do you get from the `print_r`? Are your CraigsList credentials valid?

Comment: thanks for replying R. Paulson. but its demo email Address. for Checking purpose.

Comment: yes i have Valid Craigslist credential. and my Print_r gives not proper result.

Comment: Please edit the result of `print_r` into your question. Also, print out your XML to the screen, and add that into your question separately from the code. Check it validates in a browser.